# Whats the best way to clone / duplicate a project into a new with git?

Tags: git, github

I want to clone an existing git repo for a NEW project. After the cloning the code should be developed independent from the original. I want to host the NEW project on GITHUB too.

My Workflow:

- git clone BASE_GITHUB_URL NEW_DIR
- cd /NEW_DIR

But after that my 'clone' is connected with the base repo on Github. I want to push the changes into a NEW Github Repo instad

I new its simular like 'fork', but it doesn't work with me as same the user on Github.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the reference to the original repository:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Add a reference to your own repository:

```
git remote add origin your-repos-url
```

You may want to only rename the original repository instead of removing it:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

See [`git help remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) for more informations.